# Extern global variable remains not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, variables, qt5, global, extern

Reviewing some examples here on stack overflow, I still cannot get this to compile with a global variable. Csize has been declared with extern in the renderarea.h

```
#ifndef RENDERAREA_H
#define RENDERAREA_H

#include <QBrush>
#include <QPen>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QWidget>

extern int CSize;
```

Its then set to equal 10 in the renderarea.cpp with the included renderarea.h

```
#include "renderarea.h"
#include <QTimer>

#include <QPainter>

int Xresolution = 800;
int Yresolution = 480;

int startAngle = 100 * 16;
int arcLength = 100 * 16;
int CSize = 10;
```

I then try to use it in the QRect function of the renderarea.cpp

```
//! [8]
void RenderArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */)
{
static const QPoint points[4] = {
    QPoint(800, 0),
    QPoint(0, 0),
    QPoint(0, 480),
    QPoint(800, 480)
};

QRect rect(0, 0, CSize, Csize);

QPainterPath path;
path.moveTo(20, 80);
path.lineTo(20, 30);
path.cubicTo(80, 0, 50, 50, 80, 80);

//! [8]
```

It seems that this should be OK, but get 'Csize' was not declared in this scope when compiling.
Any hints?

Comment: That is a typo. You have CSize and Csize. Remember that identifiers in c++ are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `Csize` instead of `CSize` which you declared as a global. Remember that identifiers in `c++` are case sensitive so `Csize` is different than `CSize`

Comment: Ugh! A simple typo. Much appreciated!